# Android 4.1.2 Bitmap Loading Failure

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I need to load a set of bitmaps to be used in the UI. It consists of ~15 relatively small bitmaps loaded one after another from the XML resouces. I can not see another way to do this and it seems to be working fine when tested on Android 4.0.4. But when I try to run the program on Galaxy Note 2 (with 4.1.2) I keep getting OutOfMemoryError.

Is there any known glitch/special procedure connected with loading bitmaps in 4.1.2? The set is not outstandingly big (the files together take up ~5MB) and it quite much needs to be loaded all at once for the app to function properly (it is a SurfaceView based game).

I created a AsyncTask-based loader which again works alright on 4.0.4 but throws OutOfMemoryException on 4.1.2.

One of the leads I got is that it may be connected with the number of Bitmaps loaded one after another. I would be glad if someone more experienced could comment on the case.

Comment: The files take up ~5MB? If you're using common file types(jpg/png/etc), that's the *compressed* size of the image. For the memory usage, you'll need `height * width * 4` bytes for a typical ARGB_8888 image. This is normally **far** larger than its compressed size. Run DDMS and profile the memory usage to see what's happening.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it, thanks to you and your DDMS tip :-D I never used the tool and boy if it isn't a lifesaver :D 

The problem was not directly in the bitmaps but in some other objects I created to handle the bitmap's behavior. Now it is working just fine.

Comment: Glad to help. You should consider writing up your fix as an answer. It will give some closure to the question, and might teach future searchers a bit about DDMS and how to go about finding their problems.